# Using Cocoapods with multiple platforms

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, cocoapods

I have an app that runs iOS 6 upwards. I use three open source third party libraries in this app.

1. [MRProgress](https://github.com/mrackwitz/MRProgress) - A progress view control. This library only supports iOS 7 upwards.
2. [HTProgressHUD](https://github.com/Hardtack/HTProgressHUD) - Because the previous control supports iOS 7 and on, I use this progress view control as a fallback when the app runs on iOS 6 devices.
3. [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) - To check the network availability. This library should be used when the app runs in both iOS 6 and iOS 7 devices.

This is my current `Podfile`.

```
platform :ios, '6.0'

pod 'HTProgressHUD', '~> 0.1'
pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.1'


platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'MRProgress', '~> 0.4'
pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.1'
```

Is this the correct way to go about it? Do I have to specify the `Reachability` library twice for both platforms? Also can someone please explain what the whole `platform :ios, '7.0'` line means? That's a little grey area for me.

Comment: Based on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20164489/2150138) I don not think what you want is achievable.

Comment: Hi, That question is asking if two versions of the same _library_ can be integrated. I want to support two **platforms**.

Comment: Just be aware that you will have to check at run time which HUD to use. I suggest you move to either a HUD which support both version or write your own. You could try [`SVProgressHUD`](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD)

Comment: @rckoenes Yes, I do the check and shows the progressview accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

```
  platform :ios, '6.0'

  pod 'HTProgressHUD', ' 0.1'
  pod 'Reachability', ' 3.1'
```

Comment: i think this will help both for ios 6 and 7 rather than specifying the library Twice