# Cocoapods multiple library versions in same pod file

Tags: ios, ios8, cocoapods

Hello I have the follow pod file:

```
pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.20.0'
```

And I have the error when try to pod install:

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `AFNetworking (~> 2.0)` required by `Podfile`
- `AFNetworking (= 1.1.0)` required by `RestKit/Network (0.20.0)`
- `RestKit/Network (= 0.20.0)` required by `RestKit/Core (0.20.0)`
```

RestKit require the versión 1.1.0 of AFNetworking but I want to work with 2.0 in my project how can I enable both?

I search in the documentation:
 I found **Version Conflicts** in https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html but this did not solve my problem.

Comment: Almost exact same question here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158522/using-two-versions-of-a-cocoapod-dependency

Comment: Remove the version, use without it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I think I will use the previous version of AFNetworking provided by RestKit as is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158522/using-two-versions-of-a-cocoapod-dependency), I hope in a future cocoapods could solve this problem.