# CocoaPods: There are duplicate dependencies on `AFNetworking` in `Podfile`

Tags: ios, afnetworking, cocoapods

I'm trying to use AFNetworking on my WatchOS2 project which requires AFNetworking version 2.6.  My iPhone app is using RestKit which requires AFNetworking version 1.3.6.

I have the following in my cocoapods file.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'

target 'MyApp', :exclusive => true do
  pod 'AFNetworking', '1.3.4'
  pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.25.0'
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7.3'
end

target 'MyApp WatchKit Extension', :exclusive => true do
  pod 'AFNetworking', '2.6.0'
end
```

I'm getting the following error..

> Analyzing dependencies [!] Unable to satisfy the following
>   requirements:
>
> - `AFNetworking (= 1.3.4)` required by `Podfile`
> - `AFNetworking (= 2.6.0)` required by `Podfile`

Shouldn't this work since I have ":exclusive => true" set for my target?  It should be able to build each target with a different version of AFNetworking right?

```
pod --version : 0.38.2
```

Comment: Try removing your explicit 1.3.4 include. Doesn't RestKit import it automatically?

Comment: same error when removing explicit call to version 1.3.4

Comment: I think, you could not do that ;( https://github.com/CocoaPods/Core/issues/64, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158522/using-two-versions-of-a-cocoapod-dependency

Comment: @TWilly How did you solve the problem?

Comment: I haven't found a solution yet.  So far this is not supported.  You could try using a different framework.